# How can I obtain a Pakistani letter of invitation without having to book a tour?

Tags: visas, budget, pakistan, invitation-letters

I may apply for a Pakistani tourist visa soon, and the embassy in Bern requires an invitation letter (LOI) for tourist visas.

The one I've found without booking a tour charges EUR 55 [here](http://caravanistan.com/visa/pakistan/loi/)

Is there another option?

Comment: I'm afraid this might be a shopping question: the cheaper prices one might find today are in no way guaranteed to stay the same in the future.

Comment: Did you see this thread on [Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-indian-subcontinent/pakistan/need-invitation-letter-for-pakistan-tourist-visa) which suggests contacting the hotel? It's a bit old, but I've seen the same method for other countries which require an invitation, that the hotel will provide one without charge. I took the liberty of editing so that you're not shopping (as though you need editing :-)

Comment: @Dorothy In Russia and Uzbekistan hotels usually provide it (albeit often for a fee), but I'm not aware of this being the case in Pakistan

Comment: You're right; seems that more recently hotels can't. [Lost Horizons](http://www.losthorizontreks.com/page1/) gives a good overview, as does [this](https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/pakistan-letter-of-invitation/)